# JAXB Unmarshalling polymorphic objects - collections?

Tags: java, jaxb

I have got XML as following :

```
<Temp NAME="bobo"> 
    <elem1 />
    <elem2>
        <Attri1 ID="123" />
    </elem2>
    <elem3>
        <Attri2 MOM="9" ID="7" SSS="2" />
    </elem3>
    <elem3>
         <Attri3 MOM="44" ID="4" DSC="First Test"/>
    </elem3>
</Temp>
```

I'm using annotations to map to java classes :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Temp")
public class Temp {

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name="elem1",type=elem.class),
        @XmlElement(name="elem2",type=elem.class)})
    public ArrayList<elem> elms;
}
```

---

```
public class elem {
...
}
```

---

```
public class elem1 extends elem{
...
}
```

---

```
public class elem2 extends elem{
...
}
```

---

```
public class elem3 extends elem{
...
}
```

In each element there can be lots of attributes.

Can someone please help me how to annotate the java classes correctly ?

Let me sharpen my question.
I need to build from this XML a java objects that will have 3 parameters : name of the first element(p1) , name of child element(p2), map values (p3).

The XML above will generate 4 java elem objects as following:

all java objects type is elem!

**obj1 :**

```
p1 = elem1
p2 = null
p3 = null
```

**obj2 :**

```
p1 = elem2
p2 = Attri1
p3 =  map:   key   value
             (ID,  123)
```

**obj3 :**

```
p1 = elem3
p2 = Attri2
p3 =  map:   key   value
             (MOM,  9)
             (ID,  7)
             (SSS,  2)
```

**obj4 :**

```
p1 = elem3
p2 = Attri3
p3 =  map:   key   value
             (MOM,  44)
             (ID,  4)
             (DSC,  First Test)
```

Thanks in advance!
Boris.

Comment: OK, so what happens when you try what you have?

Comment: The Thing is i don't now how to handdle the attributes correctly
for example in elem2 there is attribute name 'attri1' it can also be some other attribute , in need to now the name of the attribute and then it's value..
each attribure is different object.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to have a schema definition for your xml which covers all your cases. If indeed you need dynamic structure you need to build it in a different way with key & value pairs. For ex:

< Attribute >

```
<name >ID</name >
<value > 123</value >
```

OR

< Attribute  name="ID" value="123" >

This will give you a collection of attributes for each element. This can be represented in your schema. Once you have the schema, you can generate or create your objects

Comment: I don't have a chema definition for my xml.
I need to work with this xml because this the input my application need to work with

Comment: In that case consider DOM parser, you can internally convert them to key/value pairs like the object you have mentioned. For JAXB, as far as my knowledge goes it maps to a schema.

Comment: Queation - how could I set p1 (elem java object that is generated from the xml) value to the name of the first element - which is elem1 ? it's somthing the i need to add to elem class using annotations.. 

something like this : 

public class elem { 

   XmlAttribute public String p1; 
   XmlAttribute public String p2; 
   public Map p1; 
}